# How can I block a user agent from all sites on my server?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, useragent

*I originally this posted at [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/47012/2020), but was told I'd get a better reception here.*

---

For the last few days, I've been suffering from what appears to be a (presumably inadvertent) DDOS attack. I've been getting so many requests from an agent identifying as "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)" that apache eats through all the available memory.

Consequently, I'd like to block all requests accompanied by this user agent, so I tried doing this in httpd.conf:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

But when I restart apache it complains about using `deny` here. Without having to wrap it in a `location` or `directory` block, which would mean I'd have to add a new block for each site, is there any way I can deny access to the whole server?

---

UPDATE: The error I get

> - Restarting web server apache2
>     Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: deny not allowed
>     here
>                                                                          [fail]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like an old question now, but I wanted to do the same and found the answer from nerve above.
It's not quite right as is - seems to me that it should be `<Location "/">`, and the `SetEnvIf` needs a regular expression so the parentheses need to be quoted.

This worked for me to apply the access control across all vhosts:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; Synapse\)" bad_ua
<Location "/">
    Deny from env=bad_ua
</Location>
```

Just include that before the vhost definitions.

Comment: (For the equivalent in Apache 2.4) Be careful using `<Location>` as it overrides any other authorisation restrictions in `<Directory>`, unless you add `AuthMerging And`. See the security warning about `Require` in the apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Comment: `BrowserMatchNoCase` also works, maybe even better

Answer (score 4):

mod_rewrite can be configured at the server level according to the docs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Mozilla/4\.0 \(compatible; ICS\)" [nocase]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [forbidden,last]
```

Don't forget to escape the regex in the `RewriteCond`

Comment: Caution: the dash is not a real dash when copied. I tried editing, but SF will complain that my edit is too small. Thanks anyway, works a treat!

Comment: @ThibautBarrère if you really need to, you can bypass the small edit limit by adding an invisible `<!-- -->` to the edit

Answer (score 1):

Provided the syntax on the SetEnv lines is correct, you should be able to throw that in the conf like so:

```
<Location *>
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
</Location>
```

Should allow that to operate across all the virtual hosts - just tested on 2.2.24, worked like a charm.

Comment: This is better in that there aren't any errors, but whilst spoofing my user agent I don't get denied. Any idea why that might be?